# Разрешить доступ на папку с определенного ip

Tags: .htaccess

Как разрешить доступ на папку только одному ип адресу? Прописал в .htaccess

```
order allow deny
deny from all
allow from 192.126.12.199
```

Вот всё правильно, но никому не разрешает в папку входить, даже обладателю ипа 192.126.12.199. Меня это бесит! Всё по документации делаю, помогите пожалуйста. Постоянно с этой штуковиной геморой.
**UPD:** Оказалось синтаксис не правильный везде фигачат. Нашёл правильный:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.126.12.199
```

Comment: [Здесь][1] спрашивали?


  [1]: http://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D1%81+ip+htaccess&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

Comment: именно здесь я нашёл этот нерабочий пример, во всех сайтах пишут

Comment: После **UPD** заработало?

Comment: Да, заработало

Comment: Может и синтаксис был правильный, только в самой новой версии его изменили... У меня так однажды с Mailman было... Неделю искал проблему и ничего не понимал, а оказалось, что с апдейтом надо было и конфиг чуток подправить...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строка (**Order deny,allow**) **определяет, в какой последовательности выполняются запрещающие (deny) и разрешающие (allow) условия**.
В первом случае у вас (**order allow, deny**), сначала разрешается доступ с определенного IP, а затем тут же запрет всем, поэтому никто и не имел доступа к папке.
В случае же с **order deny, allow**, сначала запрещаем всем, и разрешаем только определенному в Allow IP.